# Asymptotic complexity of .NET collection classes

Tags: .net, collections, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Are there any resources about the asymptotic complexity (big-O and the rest) of methods of .NET collection classes (`Dictionary<K,V>`, `List<T>` etc...)?

I know that the C5 library's documentation includes some information about it ([example](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.LinkedList_1.htm)), but I'm interested in standard .NET collections too... (and PowerCollections' information would also be nice).

Comment: By complexity of a class, I'd consider the cyclomatic complexity rather than asymptotic time/space-complexity. I'd attribute the latter to the operations within a class.

Comment: You can always write a program to clock the particular function in which you're interested, plotting the results against N for various input patterns.  I think the main reason that time complexity is not documented is that this is an implementation detail, so the .NET team reserve the right to change the implementation specifics in the future.  As such, the specification for these classes is based on their functionality and not their performance.  If a specific performance characteristic is very important for your requirements, then it's probably better to implement the algorithm yourself.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

MSDN Lists these:

- [`Dictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)
- [`List<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)
- [`SortedList<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) (edit: wrong link; here's the [generic version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx))
- [`SortedDictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)

etc. For example:

> The SortedList(TKey, TValue) generic
>   class is a binary search tree with
>   O(log n) retrieval, where n is the
>   number of elements in the dictionary.
>   In this, it is similar to the
>   SortedDictionary(TKey, TValue) generic
>   class. The two classes have similar
>   object models, and both have O(log n)
>   retrieval. Where the two classes
>   differ is in memory use and speed of
>   insertion and removal:
>
> SortedList(TKey, TValue) uses less
>   memory than SortedDictionary(TKey,
>   TValue).
>
> SortedDictionary(TKey, TValue) has
>   faster insertion and removal
>   operations for unsorted data, O(log n)
>   as opposed to O(n) for
>   SortedList(TKey, TValue).
>
> If the list is populated all at once
>   from sorted data, SortedList(TKey,
>   TValue) is faster than
>   SortedDictionary(TKey, TValue).

Comment: In this (old, deleted) quote a binary search tree is confused with a sorted array-based collection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Comment: Note where they list the O notation. "The Dictionary<TKey, TValue> generic class provides a mapping from a set of keys to a set of values. Each addition to the dictionary consists of a value and its associated key. Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the Dictionary<TKey, TValue> class is implemented as a hash table."

Answer (score 34):

[This page](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/algorithms/big-oh/bigoh.html) summarises some of the time comlplexities for various collection types with Java, though they should be exactly the same for .NET.

I've taken the tables from that page and altered/expanded them for the .NET framework.
See also the MSDN pages for [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) and [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx), which detail the time complexities required for various operations.

---

### Searching

```
Type of Search/Collection Types           Complexity  Comments
Linear search Array/ArrayList/LinkedList  O(N)        Unsorted data.
Binary search sorted Array/ArrayList/     O(log N)    Requires sorted data.
Search Hashtable/Dictionary<T>            O(1)        Uses hash function.
Binary search SortedDictionary/SortedKey  O(log N)    Sorting is automated.
```

### Retrieval and Insertion

```
Operation         Array/ArrayList  LinkedList  SortedDictionary  SortedList
Access back       O(1)             O(1)        O(log N)          O(log N)
Access front      O(1)             O(1)        N.A.              N.A.
Access middle     O(1)             O(N)        N.A.              N.A.
Insert at back    O(1)             O(1)        O(log N)          O(N)
Insert at front   O(N)             O(1)        N.A.              N.A.
Insert in middle  O(N)             O(1)        N.A.              N.A.
```

Deletion should have the same complexity as insertion for the associated collection.

SortedList has a few notable peculiarities for insertion and retrieval.

*Insertion (Add method):*

> This method is an O(n) operation for
>   unsorted data, where n is Count. It is
>   an O(log n) operation if the new
>   element is added at the end of the
>   list. If insertion causes a resize,
>   the operation is O(n).

*Retrieval (Item property):*

> Retrieving the value of this property
>   is an O(log n) operation, where n is
>   Count. Setting the property is an
>   O(log n) operation if the key is
>   already in the SortedList<(Of <(TKey,
>   TValue>)>). If the key is not in the
>   list, setting the property is an O(n)
>   operation for unsorted data, or O(log
>   n) if the new element is added at the
>   end of the list. If insertion causes a
>   resize, the operation is O(n).

Note that `ArrayList` is equivalent to `List<T>` in terms of the complexity of all operations.

---

Comment: Are you sure that the complexities should be the same for .NET? I would think it's more subtle than that - for example, there's a difference between SortedDictionary, SortedList and Hashtable in .NET.

Comment: Yeah, there's no fundamental difference - the basic algorithms and data structures are going to be virtually identical. I haven't detailed SortedDictionary/SortedList, but I'll add them in now. Hashtable ought to have the same complexities as Dictionary, I believe (it's pretty much a non-generic version of it).

Comment: There is no guarantee whatsoever that the underlying implementation is comparable.

Comment: No, but this *is* the case for the official .NET implementation.

Answer (score 4):

This page presents short notes about some key pros & cons for most .NET Collections :

http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx

> | Collection | Ordering | Contiguous Storage | Direct Access | Lookup Efficiency | Manipulate Efficiency | Notes |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Dictionary | Unordered | Yes | Via Key | Key: O(1) | O(1) | Best for high performance lookups. |
> | SortedDictionary | Sorted | No | Via Key | Key: O(log n) | O(log n) | Compromise of Dictionary speed and ordering, uses binary search tree. |
> | SortedList | Sorted | Yes | Via Key | Key: O(log n) | O(n) | Very similar to SortedDictionary, except tree is implemented in an array, so has faster lookup on preloaded data, but slower loads. |
> | List | User has precise control over element ordering | Yes | Via Index | Index: O(1) Value: O(n) | O(n) | Best for smaller lists where direct access required and no sorting. |
> | LinkedList | User has precise control over element ordering | No | No | Value: O(n) | O(1) | Best for lists where inserting/deleting in middle is common and no direct access required. |
> | HashSet | Unordered | Yes | Via Key | Key: O(1) | O(1) | Unique unordered collection, like a Dictionary except key and value are same object. |
> | SortedSet | Sorted | No | Via Key | Key: O(log n) | O(log n) | Unique sorted collection, like SortedDictionary except key and value are same object. |
> | Stack | LIFO | Yes | Only Top | Top: O(1) | O(1)* | Essentially same as List except only process as LIFO |
> | Queue | FIFO | Yes | Only Front | Front: O(1) | O(1) | Essentially same as List except only process as FIFO |

Comment: The link is down, which is why it's better to also quote relevant content because now people have no way to reference this possibly helpful information.

Comment: luckily backed up why the Internet Archive here: https://web.archive.org/web/20121022141414/http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I don't know in general (the other answer just posted perhaps gives you exactly what you're after) - but you can reflect this and other methods of course using ILSpy (a little awkward with FSharp code, true) and this eventually yields this function as C#:

```
internal static a maximumElementAux<a>(SetTree<a> s, a n)
{
  while (true)
  {
    SetTree<a> setTree = s;
    if (setTree is SetTree<a>.SetOne)
    {
      break;
    }
    if (setTree == null)
    {
      return n;
    }
    SetTree<a>.SetNode setNode = (SetTree<a>.SetNode)s;
    SetTree<a> arg_23_0 = setNode.item3;
    n = setNode.item1;
    s = arg_23_0;
  }
  return ((SetTree<a>.SetOne)s).item;
  return n;
}
```

Okay so this is not exactly 'proper' code in C# terms - but the presence of the `while(true)` loop implies it can't be O(1) at least; as for what it actually is...  well, my head hurts too much to find out :)

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313896/net-framework-time-complexity-in-the-documentation

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "complexity of collection classes". Rather, different operations on these collections have different complexities. For instance, adding an element to a `Dictionary<K, V>`[...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx)

> ...approaches an *O(1)* operation. If the capacity must be increased to accommodate the new element, this method becomes an *O(n)* operation, where `n` is `Count`.

Whereas retrieving an element from a `Dictionary<K, V>`[...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx)

> ...approaches an O(1) operation.

Comment: I meant their operations, I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says it is build on a binary tree, and does not mention tracking the maximum element. If the documentation is correct, that means it should be O( log n). There used to be at least one mistake in the collections documentation (referring to an array-backed data structure as a binary search tree), but that has been corrected.

Comment: To be fair, an array is a perfectly reasonable store for a binary tree. See: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/tree-as-array.html

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, as it is of course all mapped to main memory, which provides an array-like interface (but very much skewed to preferring access to data in the same cache line). No, as this provides not a reasonable implementation for any but the smallest (and balanced) trees. A multiway tree fits much better with current processor design

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313896/net-framework-time-complexity-in-the-documentation