# What is the complexity of OrderedDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, collections

No one said that OrderedDictionary is having two copies of elements, one in a hashtable and other in a list, I can't find complexity measurements at MSDN for OrderedList.

thanks

Comment: Related post - [Asymptotic complexity of .NET collection classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/851949/465053)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have a look at

[OrderedDictionary: A generic implementation of IOrderedDictionary](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GenericOrderedDictionary.aspx?msg=2016376)

> This implementation of an ordered
>   dictionary is very good at lookup
>   operations: the array allows O(1)
>   lookups by index, and the hashtable
>   allows O(1) lookups by key. However,
>   the necessity of keeping the array
>   synchronized with the hashtable means
>   that insert/delete operations have the
>   performance disadvantage of performing
>   those operations on an array (O(n) at
>   worst). There is also, of course, the
>   extra memory requirement of storing
>   both data structures. Because of these
>   disadvantages, OrderedDictionary
>   should only be used when insert/delete
>   operations will be minimal and there
>   is a need to efficiently access
>   elements by index and/or key.