# Hashmap with "go-to-next" ability in constant time? C#

Tags: c#, list, hashmap

I am making an app where I need to process lots of strings, and I really need the O(1) performance of the hashmap (I use dictionary), for instance aDictionary["aString"]. The only slight problem is that I need to keep track of the order of things.

Basicly I need the linkedList attribute go-to-next, also O(1). I could just have a list and a dictionay, the way things work, but it is more appealing to have one collection that give me both attributes in one. Do you know of any?

I hope this is an understandable description.

Thanks for any and all help :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/486948/273200

Comment: By "O(1) performance of the hashmap," do you mean insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [Ordered Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) that does what you're describing.

However, the complexity when inserting isn't what you're asking for - but I do not think it can be improved upon (and ends up being the same as your list/dictionary implementation). See [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GenericOrderedDictionary.aspx?msg=2016376) & [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565455/what-is-the-complexity-of-ordereddictionary).

Comment: It in unfortunate that it has high insert cost. In an ideal world i want O(1): Insert, Next-element and, whats it called, "is this element in the list?"-ability.

Comment: @Cort3z, yes, in ideal world, all operations are O(1).