# .NET Framework Time complexity in the documentation

Tags: c#, .net, big-o, msdn, time-complexity

Where can I find the time complexity for methods in the standard .Net library?

I use MSDN and it occasionally mentions time complexity, but not often (I ran into a similar problem with Java).

For example I want to know if [`Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Set<'T>.MaximumElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370466.aspx)
is O(1) (which would be the case if the class explicity always tracks the max element.)
or if it's O(lg n), (which would be the case if we had to search the map for it).

This is a specific example, but surely somewhere the big-O time complexity is documented.