# Lookup a field or Index for filter search?

Tags: asp.net

I fetch have a large collection (35k+ - list of products)

```
for each item_cache in products_cache
    list.Add(New Products With {
        .product_id = item_cache.id,
        .product_name = item_cache.name,
        .moreHere = item_cache.moreHere,
        .moreHere = item_cache.moreHere,
        .moreHere = item_cache.moreHere,
        .moreHere = item_cache.moreHere
        })
next

return list.Tolist
```

The params we currently have are all in strings (home.aspx?p_name='Shirts').

After I have the list collection, is it better to search through string or search through index?

```
return list.where(function(c) c.product_name = 'Shirts')
```

Or should I retrieve first the index (PK) of the string

```
Dim p_id As Integer = dataGetIdOfProduct('Shirts')

return list.where(function(c) c.product_id = p_id)
```

Comment: Not much difference, if any, as they appear to all be  cached anyway.

Comment: What if it's not cached? Are there any difference at all? Is the 'string' lookup a perf degrade?

Comment: Using a List<T> I doubt there will be any difference. If you use something like Dictionary<TKey, TValue> that you can access the items via the key, it will be quicker to use that key.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851949/asymptotic-complexity-of-net-collection-classes for a little more info

Comment: How about vice-versa, I lookup on the <TValue> and not the <TKey>? Is that alright?