# Is there an equivalent to std::deque (fast inserts at both ends) in C#?

Tags: c#, collections

I need something that's cache efficient, but where I can also insert quickly at both front and back. C# has Queue, but the documentation doesn't say anything about the underlying implementation. For example, it could be implemented as some kind of linked list.

So is there an equivalent to C++ std::deque in C#?

Comment: You can check Microsoft Reference Source to know more about the implementation and see if it fits your requirements [**Queue on MS Reference Source**](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/queue.cs)

Comment: According to the above, Queue<T> is implemented as a ring buffer.

Comment: Just to have a direct link, the generic implementation is on here: [**Queue<T> on MS Reference Source**](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs)

Comment: I think LinkedList<T>  is what you're looking for.

Comment: @mishamosher Thanks!

Comment: @lexx9999: `LinkedList<T>` is .NET's equivalent to C++ `std::list<T>`.  `deque<T>` is quite a different arrangement.

Comment: @lexx9999 A linked list is what I am trying to avoid. It has poor cache performance.

Comment: @Noone you're welcome (:

Comment: @mishamosher Looking at Queue<T> source, it seems that it's implemented as a contiguous ring buffer, so cache performance should be good. I would answer this question myself, but a user does not have a name ;)

Comment: @Noone However, its not a bad idea to answer it, Q&A style (or self-answered) questions are encouraged by the FAQ of Stack Overflow, they allow for anyone that searches for your question to rapidly see that it has a working solution and not ignore it just because the answered check was not present.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599127/c-sharp-equivalent-for-c-vector-or-deque ?

Comment: @JimMischel The user that asks this question specifically requires an equivalent to `std::deque`, and not an equivalent to c++ `vector` _or_ `deque`. Users without much experience reaching this question and seeing it as duplicate can think that `vector` is the same as `deque`. I do not think that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Ever find a solution for this? The main issue I have with Queue is that it is a ring buffer, which means it does not work well when one with many items needs to be resized.

With std::deque, or my implementation of “bigdeque”, which assumes that it will be relatively big, and creates larger “pages”