# Adding clones to a list is slow

Tags: c#, list, performance, object, clone

I'm trying to speed up a loop, which is cloning **2_500_000** objects.
The clone itself is taking **800 ms** for the entire loop but when I'm adding them to a list, it's taking **3 seconds**..

```
List<T> list = new List<T>();

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

foreach(T entity in listSource)
{
    T entityCloned = GetEntityClone(entity); // Taking 800ms totally

    if (entityCloned != null)
        list.Add(entityCloned);
}

sw.Stop();
```

Could you please help me to find out why those `Add`s are taking so much time?

Comment: Try `list.AddRange(listSource.Select(s => GetEntityClone(s)).Where(s => s != null));`

Comment: If the only way for a clone to be `null` is that the original itself is `null`, then you might want to write `listSource.Where(s => s != null).Select(s => GetEntityClone(s))` instead (filter before cloning)

Comment: `List<T> list = new List<T>(2500000);` in order to prevent memory reallocation

Comment: I just tried AddRange with Linq and setting the internal capacity of the list but it's not changing at all :'(

Comment: O(N) access to list is guaranteed by expanding [0, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, ...]. Reallocating takes time which is why you get theese "extreme" timings

Comment: What is T? A class, struct? Classes are passed by reference. Inserting the Nth reference into a List shouldn't take long. Structs though will have to be copied. Inserting a struct into a list requires making a copy of the struct returned by `GetEntityClone()`. Copying large structs takes time

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: it seems that `T` is *class*: `if (entityCloned != null)` is of no use in case of `struct`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko there's no info so we all guess. We can't even know how long cloning really takes, what the actual code looks like, how it performed *after* adding the capacity.

Comment: @JulienDinis use BenchmarkDotNet instead of trying to measure times using Stopwatch. Right now you don't know if your timings are affected by other code, the test harness, the garbage collector or reallocations. BenchmarkDotNet collects enough samples to ensure the times are correct and captures GCs, allocations/deallocations etc. Without your actual code people can only guess - setting a reference inside a preallocated list is *not* slow. We'd need access to the actual code to test it and profile it with BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: How about simply `new List<T>(listSource.Count)` ? If 33% of the performance can be shaved off by a static array, giving the list an initial capacity would do the same thing.

Comment: And the main reason why a list is taking a lot of time to use in this manner might be because of garbage collection. On its way to 2.5m items, a total of 21 reallocations have been done on that list, moving a total of 4.1m items from one array to another, getting rid of these allocations and memory movement by specifying the capacity to begin with will help a lot.

Comment: I already tried that, it's not working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved some time (around 33%) by using array instead of list:

MyObject class defitinion:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Flag { get; set; }

    public static MyObject GetEntityClone(MyObject obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return null;

        var newObj = new MyObject()
        {
            Id = obj.Id,
            Flag = obj.Flag
        };

        return newObj;
    }
}
```

Code:

```
var sourceList = new List<MyObject>();

// let's mock the source data, every 27th element will be null
for (int i = 0; i < 2500000; ++i)
{
    if (i % 27 != 0)
        sourceList.Add(new MyObject { Id = i, Flag = (i % 2 == 0) });
}

var destArray = new MyObject[2500000];

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

var currentElement = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sourceList.Count; ++i)
{
    MyObject entityCloned = MyObject.GetEntityClone(sourceList[i]);

    if (entityCloned != null)
        destArray[currentElement++] = entityCloned;
}

var result = new MyObject[currentElement];
Array.Copy(destArray, 0, result, 0, currentElement);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately looping over many things and deep copying objects is going to take time. I don't think that 3 seconds is necessarily an unreasonable amount of time for it to take.

But you can potentially improve the speed.

Firstly, if you know how many items the result list will need to hold before hand you can [set the internal capacity beforehand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.capacity?view=netframework-4.7.2) to prevent the list from having to resize. Resizing is an expensive activity which can be avoided if necessary. This can be done by manually changing the capacity property of the list or by passing the capacity as a [constructor argument for the list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Once the capacity has been allocated, [the complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of adding to the list should be `O(1)`, no reaollcations (which are a `O(n)` complexity task [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35205522/6306281)) will be needed. It is unlikely that adding to the list in this case will be the bottleneck.

You could also remove null values from the initial list which you are copying from beforehand to remove the need for the if statement which has to be evaluated every time. Using [linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/):

`var noNulls = listSource.where(o => o != null)`

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't filter null values because my clone method is filtering by itself, I already tried to set the internal capacity by giving the size of my source list but it's not changing at all..

Comment: It might be useful to add your clone method to the question so we can see what is happening in there. Would you be able to do this?

Comment: OP mentioned that deep copying does not take significant amount of time, but adding to a list does. One may argue that OP made mistake and did not measure properly, but this should be investigated before going directly to deep cloning issue.

Comment: Good point. I do think that adding to the list is unlikely to be the bottleneck though, especially if OP has tried adding a capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following do the work in parallel:

```
ConcurrentBag<T> list = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
Parallel.ForEach(listSource, entity =>
{
    T entityCloned = GetEntityClone(entity); //Taking 800ms totally
    if (entityCloned != null)
        list.Add(entityCloned);

});

var listVersion = list.ToList();
```